# Why does my PriorityBlockingQueue in Java not sort properly?

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

For some reason when I add to the priority queue, it doesn't sort my strings entirely alphabetically and I can't see why.

This is the code which adds to the PriorityBlockingQueue:

```
String toAdd = String.format("%s/%s", directory, s);
outputData.add(toAdd);
```

But I get not entirely sorted output (only first few lines but you can see it's not sorted):

```
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/a.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/a.java
../StartingTree/files/abknl/aqybc/aeph.java
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/bnjuxxdi.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/dyetqhsch/bpg.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/bbxudleuf/mxb/fe/ndmg/axapxuco.html
../StartingTree/files/abknl/aqybc/atyuojdu.txt
```

And this is the real (first part) of sorted output from the expected-output file:

```
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/a.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/a.java
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/bnjuxxdi.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/bnjuxxdi.java
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/bsqsq.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/bsqsq.java
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/ds.class
../StartingTree/files/abknl/apfmpohgyh/ds.java
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get the following result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726452/why-do-i-get-the-following-result)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to iterate the `PriorityBlockingQueue` and print the elements.

Note that a Priority Queue data structure (AKA [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)) does not guarantee ordering - it guarantees that the head is minimal, but no order guarantee on any of the following nodes.

If you want your data maintained sorted - I suggest using something like [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) (Note however it is a set - thus it does not allow duplicate entrees), or maintaining a sorted [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

If you want to get the sorted elements using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` - you should iteratively delete the head and output the new head - until the priority queue is exhausted. It will guarantee an ordered output.

Comment: Oh, I had in my head that every element would be perfectly sorted, I had no idea it was only the head which was minimal. I'll just use another structure and then write my own code for insertion :)

Any recommendations on data structures in multi-thread programs (i.e. where more than one thread might try to access my data concurrently) ?

Comment: +1 Or (cf javadoc):  "*If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.*"

Comment: @Geesh_SO: If you don't have duplicate elements, I suggest using a `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. See new version of the answer.