# Why do I get the following result?

Tags: java, concurrency, priority-queue

I have done the following test to see how a

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<String> pq = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(2);
     pq.put("Sing");
     pq.put("Sing2");
     pq.put("Sing3");
     pq.put("Sing4");
     pq.put("Sing10");
     pq.put("Sing11");
     pq.put("Sing12");
     pq.put("Sing13");
     for (String s1: pq)
     {
         System.out.print(s1 +" ");
     }
```

The result I get is:

```
 Sing Sing10 Sing11 Sing13 Sing2 Sing3 Sing12 Sing4
```

Now how the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue%28int%29) says it should order them in their natural order if no comparator specified at construction time. Hoever as you can see the result is not ordered at all.

Secondly the initial capacity I set was of 2, why there is such an option if the bound is actually not set? What's the point? I understand that the api specify that it's an unbounded priority queue however why making a constructor taking an initial capacity at all if it cannot set any bound of it?

So basically I have got 2 questions:

**1)** Why the order of the result above posted does not follow the natural order of the elements?

**2)** What is the purpose of having a constructor with a parameter "initial capacity" which does not actually set the bound. In the [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) it's reasonable as it sets the bound however it does not happen in the PriorityBlockingQueue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The natural order for strings is alphabetical order. Output is correct.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal It's not. `Sing12` should come between `Sing11` and `Sing13`...

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: look carefully.  `Sing3 Sing12 Sing4` is not alphabetical.  `Sing12` should be between `Sing11` and `Sing13`

Comment: @SteveP., Russell Uhl: Ah, missed that one.

Comment: @assylias that thread just cover the first bit of my question.

Comment: edited it so now is clearer

Comment: ops was missing the 2 in the constructor.. fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order is guaranteed when you access the head with poll, remove, peek or take for example, but not when you iterate:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

This will yield the expected output:

```
String s;
while ((s = pq.poll()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

outputs:

```
Sing
Sing10
Sing11
Sing12
Sing13
Sing2
Sing3
Sing4
```

---

> What is the purpose of having a constructor with a parameter "initial capacity" which does not actually set the bound.

The initial capacity is not a bound. The queue is backed by an array - by setting the initial capacity you can avoid unnecessary array resizing (similarly to ArrayList's constructor).

Comment: +1 did not know that.  Interesting.  Given that the queue is specifically in priority order, I would make the same assumption about iterating.  I bet this design decision has caused a heap of bugs.

Comment: @Gray I've seen it a couple of times on SO indeed.

Comment: @Gray I made the same assumption, too.  In some ways it makes perfect sense, but...

Comment: @assylias what about the second bit of the question? I haven't received a through response yet.

Comment: @Rollerball: and mine, but it's the same answer.

Answer (score 5):

The javadoc says:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the PriorityBlockingQueue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

You will get elements in order when using `peek()/poll()/take()`. But not when iterating.

To answer your second question: the queue is implemented as an array of objects internally. Setting an initial capacity allows avoiding too many array copies when the queue grows and the number of elements exceeds the capacity. Just like an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the PriorityBlockingQueue in any particular
>   order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()). Also, method drainTo can be used to remove
>   some or all elements in priority order and place them in another
>   collection.

Answer (score 0):

The initial capacity is the size with which the container storing your elements is initialized with @-). As elements are added, the capacity grows automatically. It depends on the growth policy (defined by the underlying container) what are the costs of extending the size of the container.

`PriorityBlockingQueue` is an unbounded blocking queue by its [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). The purpose of having such a constructor with a parameter "initial capacity" is to initialize the underlying container with a value which makes sense for the actual use case. This can not be foreseen by the implementor of the `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` is an optionally-bounded blocking queue by its [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). So the parameter has - if set - the function to act as an upper bound.

Comment: Look again.  It's not in lexicographical order.

Comment: `Sing3 Sing12 Sing4` is out of order. I missed seeing that too.

Comment: you are both right - i removed the wrong answer to the first question - thanks

Comment: @Jost so why with LinkedBlockingQueue  it does set a bound?

Comment: @Rollerball because PriorityBlockingQueue is an _unbounded_ blocking queue by [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)